# Why is year returning value of 1 when it should be increasing with each loop?

Tags: swift, loops, while-loop

If a flower grows 1cm every year, how long will it take to be 15.24cm?

```
var year = 0
var length = 0.0

while length <= 15.24 {
    if length.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0) == 0 {
        year += 1
    }
    length += 0.01
}

print(year)
```

My approach:

1. Year increments by 1 each time the length is a whole number (because rate is 1cm/year)
2. Goal is to calculate how long it'll take to be fully grown (15.24cm)
3. Year should return 15

Why's it only returning 1?

Comment: Should that equality be not equal?

Comment: `Double` cannot represent 0.01 precisely. `length.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0) == 0` rarely becomes `true`. Use scaled `Int` or `Decimal` if you need exact comparison.

Comment: print the value of  `length.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0)` before the `if`

Comment: @OOPer Could you respond with what that may look like? I'm still learning and don't know how to use scaled `Int` or `Decimal`

Comment: FWIW: this can be computed with a a simple equation, no need for a loop: `size = growth_per_year * years`, so `years = size / growth_per_year`. (This doesn't answer the "problematic code" provided, however.)

Comment: @user2864740 That's how I solved it the first time :). Since I'm studying a chapter on loops, I want to see if I can apply it to this problem as well.

Comment: Without a fixed precision it's not really well suited to a loop (and even with a fixed precision..) D: If a fixed precision is okay, consider converting the values to an integer first: 15.24cm = 152400um. This should help avoid some 'math fun' and given more exact units in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of scaled `Int`:

```
var year = 0
var length: Int = 0_00 //1_00 represents 1.00 cm

while length <= 15_24 {
    if length % 1_00 == 0 {
        year += 1
    }
    length += 0_01
}

print(year) //-> 16
```

(Underscores (`_`) are ignored in Swift numeric literals, it's added just for readability.)

Seems you need to modify a little bit, if you expect 15.